# Как изменить размер canvas javasript / jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, canvas

Пробую работать с canvas. Сейчас canvas появляется при нажатии на кнопку и отрисовывается линия. Хочу перед появлением canvas и "рисованием" линии изменить размеры canvas на свои собственные, но получается что я просто растягиваю картинку (меняю свойства css через jQuery). Понимаю что это не правильно, но не могу понять как изменить размеры исходного полотна, а не тупо растянуть изображение.

Приведу пример кода:

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $("#canvas").width(1500);
    $("#canvas").height(1500);
    $("#canvas").toggle();

    ctx.strokeStyle= "red";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(60, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(60, 100);
    ctx.width = 1500;
    ctx.height = 1500;
    ctx.stroke();
});
```

Весь код здесь:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qREYeM

Comment: Как подсказывают тут http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27662327/jquery-resize-a-canvas-without-scaling может помочь `$("#canvas").prop('width', 1500); $("#canvas").prop('height', 1500);`

Comment: Помогло, спасибо